# Stimulsoft - Fix number of record per page

Tags: stimulsoft

I would like to create new pages when the maximum number of results per page, for DataBand is reached.
I've two databands in the report and I want to break the first databand when the records exceed 5.
The second databand has the same behavior but the limit of records are 3.
The example of expected result is the link below.

https://slack-files.com/T0A4P7U2K-F0FBQM31Q-eb8f2d6554

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried some code like below?

```
if (Line > 1 && Line%5==1)
Engine.NewPage();
```

Comment: DataBand1 should be printed on each page with a maximum of five records for each page. If I use the following command: 
"if (Line > 1 && Line%5==1)
Engine.NewPage();"
All of subsequent databand go to the next page and I want only databand1 go to the next page.